# How to log "220 server ready" message after connecting with Apache FTPSClient

Tags: java, ftp, ftps, apache-commons-net

I'm writing a simple FTPS client using Apache Commons Net. Everything works fine, but the initial "server ready" message isn't being logged. I call `connect()` and do a `getReplyString()` immediately afterward, and all it logs is `234 Enabling TLS, awaiting negotiations` even though I know the server is sending a message after it connects:

`220 FTPS (Version  Fri Jan 22 19:49:50 2016) server ready.`

I've even used `getReplyStrings()` to see if there are more than one message, but it still only shows the one `234 Enabling TLS, awaiting negotiations` message. I have a feeling it's because that's the only reply to the `AUTH TLS` command that gets automatically issued when I connect (explicit TLS).

I made a hack that scrapes the ProtocolCommandListener output and grabs the message that way, but I'd rather do it correctly. I have a feeling I'm missing something simple. Can anyone help?

Code:

```
FTPSClient ftpsclient = new FTPSClient("TLSv1.2");

// my hacked attempt to get the message
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos,true,"utf-8");
ftpsclient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(ps, true));

logMessage("Connecting to FTP-SSL server [" + HOST + "] on port [" + PORT + "]...", 1);
ftpsclient.connect(HOST, PORT);
_logger.debug("Output: "+ baos.toString()); 
if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftpsclient.getReplyCode())) {
    throw new Exception("Failed to connect to [" + HOST + "]\n" + ftpsclient.getReplyString());
}
logMessage(ftpsclient.getReplyString(), 1);
```

Output:

```
[Jan 22, 16:49:50] INFO logMessage() - Connecting to FTP-SSL server [HOST] on port [PORT]...
[Jan 22, 16:49:55] DEBUG - Output: 220 FTPS (Version  Fri Jan 22 19:49:50 2016) server ready.
AUTH TLS
234 Enabling TLS, awaiting negotiations.
[Jan 22, 16:49:55] INFO  EDIDataExtractor.logMessage() - 234 Enabling TLS, awaiting negotiations.
```